# include the url in mysql field in creating a menu

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make the generated list from mysql data clickable or url is included. Is there a way to do this? part of the field is menu_parent and menu_url.
This is the sample generated list...

```
Boats
Cars
Trucks
```

when one of the item is clicked, it will be directed to the corresponding link or url in the mysql.

this is the mysql fields

```
menu item  |  menu_url
boats      |   boats.html
cars       |   cars.html
trucks     |   trucks.html'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$sql->execute();
while($r=$sql->fetch()){
 echo "<a href='".$r['menu_url']."'>".$r['menu item']."</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Foreach Other Than While...

```
 $result = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
        $query = $glb_connection->prepare($result);
        $query->execute();
        $qry = $query->fetchAll();
        foreach ($qry as $menu) {
        echo "<a href='".$menu['menu_url']."'>".$menu['menu item']."</a>";
    }
```

Comment: i tried to integrate your codes and it is not working.or current code is this ..http://i.stack.imgur.com/UtSQF.jpg. appreciate your help.

Comment: The code is in PDO, You must first connect to MySQL according to PDO then you will have variable like $db, or $connect or whatever you call it..

Comment: The Above code works as you want, from my understanding....what problem did you get, or Error?